# Terminal GUI to achieve Up arrow function

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, rxtx

I am using `RXTX` library for serial port communication in java.

For GUI(to show it like a terminal) using java swings text area.

In normal terminal tools if we do up arrow we get previously executed commands or if we do backspace it will delete only the command and not terminal prompt (e.g.) `<terminal_tool\:>ls` - backspace will delete only ls.

In my case since it is text area Up arrow simply moves cursor to the above line and backspace deletes all contents. 
Is there any way I can achieve the same way as in normal terminal tools or any dedicated API available for this?

Please help.

Comment: Key strokes are handled by the key bindings API, you'll need to override the arrow up key binding

Comment: @MadProgrammer similarly backspace deletes all the contents in Jtextarea but i need to delete only the commands and not terminal prompt..is there any way for this?

Comment: You could use a `DocumentFilter`